# How can I create a pandas series based on two other series and their index?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Given two pandas series with the same index:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([5, 11], columns=['A'], index=[1, 2])
b = pd.DataFrame([2, 3], columns=['B'], index=[1, 2])

    A  
1   5  
2  11  

   B  
1  2  
2  3
```

What is an efficient way to create a new series with the same index where each value is `(value of A - index) / value of B`, i.e.

```
  C
1 2  (= (5 - 1) / 2)
2 3  (= (11 - 2) / 3)
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit: I noticed that the title of my question is about series, but the text and the answers are about dataframes. So in case anybody wants to do the same with series a and b, this is how: `(a - a.index) / b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
c = ((a['A'] - a.index) / b['B'])
#1    2.0
#2    3.0
#dtype: float64
```

If you wanted the results as a DataFrame:

```
c = pd.DataFrame(c, columns=["C"])
print(c)
#     C
#1  2.0
#2  3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Option 1

```
a.A.sub(a.index).div(b.B).to_frame('C')

     C
1  2.0
2  3.0
```

---

#### Option 2

```
a.join(b).eval('C = (A - index) / B', inplace=False)

    A  B    C
1   5  2  2.0
2  11  3  3.0
```